# col disappear when small the screen using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**I have a problem with these 3 cards....when it's a large screen they fit perfect but when small the screen one of the col disappears and does not fit into the page:**

-I tried to give height when it's mobile size but still the same problem.

Live Page preview:https://melad99.github.io/3-Column-Preview-Card/

Comment: See [ask] and post as [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0):

The first col has the `col-sm-3` class on it and the other 2 have `col-sm` as their class, thats why they are behaving differently

Comment: i deleted it and still the same problem